# Configuring Federation between two RabbitMQ environments, but no `links` are encountered

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to configure federation between two `RabbitMQ` environments using the `Federation Plugin`.

I followed [this](https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/cluster_migration.html#queue_federation) article. But when I look in `Federation Status` page under `Admin` tab, then I can't see any `link`. All I see is `... no links ...`.

Can anyone show me the right direction to make federation work? I have questions like, do I have to create the `policy` on the `upstream` or the `downstream` server? And the same for the configuration of the `Federation Upstream`.

I only want queue federation, no exchange federation. In other words, I only want single consumption of a message. The article I mentioned above looks perfectly fitting for this. But unfortunately I can't see any link in `Federation Status` ...

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

**Downstream RMQ specs**

- A cluster with 3 nodes
- Uses SSL
- version 3.7.13 Erlang 21.3

**Upstream RMQ specs**

- Single node, not clustered
- No SSL
- version 3.7.5 Erlang 20.2

**Federation configuration on downstream RMQ cluster**

*New policy:*

I added a policy with a pattern exactly matching the queue name and with definition `federation-upstream-set: all`:

```
Pattern:    RmqQueue
Apply to:   queues
Definition: federation-upstream-set: all
Priority:   0
```

When I look at the Queues tab, I can see that this policy is applied to the queue.

*New Federation Upstream:*

I created a new `Federation Upstream` from downstream (cluster) to upstream (single-node). Only name and uri is filled, other fields are left empty.

```
General parameters
URI              amqp://<username>:<password>@hostnamesinglenode
Prefetch Count   ?
Reconnect Delay 
Ack Mode         on-confirm
Trust User-ID    ○

Federated exchange parameters
Exchange         ?
Max Hops         ?
Expires 
Message TTL 
HA Policy        ?

Federated queue parameters
Queue            ?
```

Comment: Please share an exact transcript of the commands or actions you took. What is the output of [this command](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation-reference.html#status)?

Comment: @LukeBakken I edited my post, is this information sufficient for you? The problem is actually, I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I only see `... no links ...` in `Federation Status`, but I can't find the reason why there is no link.

Comment: The configuration appears correct. Is anything logged by RabbitMQ?

Comment: @LukeBakken What I encountered is when I restart the `RabbitMQ service`, then the link is directly set up and running. And sometimes when I remove a federation upstream, rename and recreate it, then the UI is not aware of the name change. After service restart, then name change is applied in Federation status page. So I begin thinking that a `service restart` is required when adding or editing federation upstreams?

Comment: No a service restart is not necessary. As I asked before, is anything logged by RabbitMQ? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 10. and logging does not show anyting special. When there is a running link, then I can see logging when a connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

Upstream servers are the servers towards messages are published initially. Downstream servers are where the messages get forwarded to, so messages should be federated from the **upstream server** to **downstream server**. All configuration settings that you need to do, should be done on the "new" server, the server to where you want you messages to be moved (the downstream server).

Here is a [link](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-07-08-migrate-between-plans-rabbitmq-queue-federation.html) with more images.

Please note that you can move the publisher and/or the consumer in any order, after you have configured the federation. The federated queue will ONLY retrieve messages when it has run out of messages locally, when it has consumers that need messages, or when the upstream queue has "spare" messages that are not being consumed.

Comment: Thank you for this information, but I knew all this. And it's actually not an answer on my question.

Comment: I thought you said "do I have to create the policy on the upstream or the downstream server?", and then "I created a new Federation Upstream from downstream (cluster) to upstream (single-node).", where it should be from upstream to downstream.

Comment: okay, thanks. But the actual problem was I couldn't see any links. But I figured it out, I know why it didn't create a link. It was because the broker definitions weren't the same.

Comment: I see, glad you sorted it out :)